# How to achieve this drop down container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is like a dropdown menu but doesn't accept any ontap function, just readability.
Please see the image to know how it looks and works

[image]

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/master-flutter-essentials-intensify-powerful-uis-d2e2aa6c79b8) could help!

Comment: ExpansionTile, ExpansionPanel, etc.. coud help you check it out https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample

Comment: hi can I ask another question. Nobody answered it yet.please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a listview of widgets and wrap each widget in the list with flutter-expandable 
Check this
https://github.com/aryzhov/flutter-expandable/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hi, please can I ask you another question? Nobody answered it yet.

Comment: Yes go ahead if i can help

Comment: hey man can you please check this codde?<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168700/is-this-code-correct-im-not-able-to-retrieve-any-data-from-firebase-though-the>