# Firestore does not return data as expected

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I tried getting all documents with their subcollection called 'userProducts' from a Firestore collection called 'products'. There's no error returned in the run console but I'm getting no data from the database. Could you please see my code and correct my mistakes.

This is the page where I'm trying to display the data from Firestore:

```
class Shop extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _ShopState createState() => _ShopState();
}

class _ShopState extends State<Shop> {
  String postOrientation = "grid";
  String shopOrientation = "grid";
  bool isFollowing = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  List<Prod> finalProductsList = [] ;
  productsList() async {
    List list_of_products = await Firestore.instance.collection("products")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((val) => val.documents);
    for (int i=0; i<list_of_products.length; i++) {
      Firestore.instance.collection("products").document(
          list_of_products[i].documentID.toString()).collection("userProducts").snapshots().listen(CreateListofProducts);
    }
  }
  CreateListofProducts(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
    var docs = snapshot.documents;
    for (var Doc in docs) {
      finalProductsList.add(Prod.fromFireStore(Doc));
    }
  }
  buildProducts() {
    if (isLoading) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else if (finalProductsList.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        color: kSecondaryColor,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "No Products",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return finalProductsList.toList();
    }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
          title: Text('Shop',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily :"MajorMonoDisplay",
                fontSize:  35.0 ,
                color: Colors.white),),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: kSecondaryColor),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton( icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
        });
      }
    ),],
 ),
     backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
    body:NeuomorphicContainer(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0 ),
width: 675,
                  height: 789,
                  color: Color(0xFFFeFeFe),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  intensity: 0.260,
                  offset: Offset(5.0,5.0),blur: 3.0,
                  style: NeuomorphicStyle.Pressed,
                  child: buildProducts(),
                ),
);
 }
}
```

This is  the page where the custom model class is declared:

```
class Prod extends StatefulWidget {
  final String prodId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String price;
  final String productname;
  final String details;
  final String color;
  final String composition;
  final String washandcare;
  final String sizeandfit;
  final String shopmediaUrl;
  final dynamic likes;

  Prod({
    this.prodId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.price,
    this.details,
    this.productname,
    this.color,
    this.composition,
    this.washandcare,
     this.sizeandfit,
    this.shopmediaUrl,
    this.likes,
//    String id,
  });

  factory Prod.fromFireStore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Prod(
      prodId: doc['prodId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      price: doc['price'],
      productname: doc['productname'],
      details: doc['details'],
      shopmediaUrl: doc['shopmediaUrl'],
      color:doc['color'],
   composition:doc['composition'],
   washandcare:doc['washandcare'],
    sizeandfit:doc['sizeandfit'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
  }

  int getLikeCount(likes) {
    //if no likes return 0
    if (likes == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    // if the key is explicitly set to true, add a like
    likes.values.forEach((val) {
      if (val == true) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }

  @override
  _ProdState createState() => _ProdState(
    prodId: this.prodId,
    ownerId: this.ownerId,
    username: this.username,
    price: this.price,
    details: this.details,
    productname: this.productname,
    color: this.color,
   composition: this.composition,
    washandcare: this.washandcare,
    sizeandfit: this.sizeandfit,
    shopmediaUrl: this.shopmediaUrl,
    likes: this.likes,
    likeCount: getLikeCount(this.likes),
  );
}

class _ProdState extends State<Prod> {
  final String currentUserId = currentUser?.id;
  final String prodId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String price;
  final String productname;
  final String details;
  final String color;
  final String composition;
  final String washandcare;
  final String sizeandfit;
  final String shopmediaUrl;
  int likeCount;
  Map likes;
  bool isLiked;
  bool showHeart = false;
  bool details1 = true;
  _ProdState({
    this.prodId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.price,
    this.details,
    this.productname,
    this.color,
    this.composition,
    this.washandcare,
    this.sizeandfit,
    this.shopmediaUrl,
    this.likes,
    this.likeCount,
  });
 buildPostHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: usersRef.document(ownerId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
        bool isPostOwner = currentUserId == ownerId;
        return NeuomorphicContainer(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0 ),


          color: Color(0xFFFeFeFe),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          intensity: 0.260,
          offset: Offset(5.0,5.0),blur: 3.0,
          style: NeuomorphicStyle.Pressed,
          child: Column(
              children:  <Widget> [
             ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
              title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => showProfile(context, profileId: user.id),
                child: Text(
                  user.username,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: kText,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
//            subtitle: Text(location,
//              style: TextStyle(color: kGrey),),
              trailing: isPostOwner
                  ? IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert,color: Colors.white,),
                onPressed: () => handleDeletePost(context),
              )
                  : Text(''),
            ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onDoubleTap: handleLikePost,
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,

                    children: <Widget>[
                      cachedNetworkImage(shopmediaUrl),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0)),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: handleLikePost,
                      child: Icon(
                        isLiked ? Icons.favorite  : Icons.favorite_border,
                        size: 28.0,
                        color: kIcon,
                      ),
                    ),
//                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1.0)),
                    Container(
//                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "$likeCount likes",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
//                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => showProductComments(
                        context,
                        prodId: prodId,
                        ownerId: ownerId,
                        shopmediaUrl: shopmediaUrl,
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.chat,
                        size: 28.0,
                        color: kIcon,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
//          Row(
//            children: <Widget>[
//
//            ],
//          ),
                SizedBox( height:10.0,),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "$productname ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: kText,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
//              SizedBox( height:10.0,),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[Container(
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "₹$price ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: kText,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),],
                ),
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isLiked = (likes[currentUserId] == true);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        buildPostHeader(),
//       
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in my opinion inside function productList() your list list_of_products is empty. Try to debug to verify my words. I suggest refactor this code. Go through some firebase docs/tutorial to see how to persist firebase documents to list.

Comment: it didnt work,can't figure out whats wrong.Is there any other way to get all doc from  products collection with thier subcollections?All the docs have a sub collection of the same name(userProducts)

Answer (score 0):

I think productsList() is not called.

Try placing it inside initstate.

Comment: it didnt work,can't figure out whats wrong.Is there any other way to get all doc from  products collection with thier subcollections?All the docs have a sub collection of the same name(userProducts)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
CreateListofProducts(QuerySnapshot snapshot)async
  {
    var docs = snapshot.documents;
    for (var Doc in docs)
    {
      finalProductsList.add(Prod.fromFireStore(Doc.data)); //.data
    }
  }
```

and then inside

```
class Prod extends StatefulWidget 

factory Prod.fromFireStore(Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
    return Prod(
      prodId: doc['prodId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      price: doc['price'],
      productname: doc['productname'],
      details: doc['details'],
      shopmediaUrl: doc['shopmediaUrl'],
      color:doc['color'],
      composition:doc['composition'],
      washandcare:doc['washandcare'],
      sizeandfit:doc['sizeandfit'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
}
```

Maybe there is something else, but you should correct it

Comment: it didnt work,can't figure out whats wrong.Is there any other way to get all doc from  products collection with thier subcollections?All the docs have a sub collection of the same name(userProducts)

Comment: I found this interesting article. Take a look

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166